# Images loaded in ImageView disappear on fragment reLoad

Tags: android-fragments, android-imageview

I have a Fragment to edit contents. In this Fragment I  have ImageView which displays image picked from gallery or camera This Fragment in turn also opens another fragment. From this fragment when I goes back to Edit fragment displayed image goes disappear and 
ImageViews goes blank and every thing else (Edittext,Textviews) remains persistant(filled)

Note that when I goes back to edit fragment its OnCreateView is called not OnCreate method 
for example when we replace fragment with another fragment and Pops Back to previous one its OnCreateView method is called first

I can't understand what is happening pls Help.

Comment: I'm having this issue too. Maybe it has to do with the latest SDK? Which SDK are you using?

Comment: have you find the solution ? I have the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65056767/is-it-normal-if-my-image-from-camera-in-imageview-disappear-after-segue-to-anoth?noredirect=1#comment115014885_65056767

Answer (score 2):

> old, but maybe this can help others.

I solving this by set source path to variable, then call in onResume() method.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //set again your ImageView source here..
}
```