# is it normal if my image from camera in ImageView disappear after segue to another fragment using navigation component?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I try to capture an image using camera then the image result will be placed on my ImageView in a fragmentA like the code below, so it it **NOT** fetching an image path from Server then place it in ImageView using Glide Library, I take an image from camera.

```
val image_uri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
photoImageView.setImageURI(image_uri)
```

and then, I move to next destination using this code (from fragmentA to fragmentB)

```
val toFragmentB = AFragmentDirections.actionGlobalBFragment()
findNavController().navigate(toFragmentB)
```

but when I get back to FragmentA, the image in ImageView is disappear. I believe `onDestroy` in FragmentA is not called when I segue to FragmentB. is this normal ?

so to solve this issue, to make the image persist, first I have to 'store' the image in ViewModel ? am I right?

Comment: Can you add `setRetainInstance(true)` in `onCreateView` of this frgment ?

Comment: @Zain thank you, but I have tried to add it but the image still disappear :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#states), especially [view and fragment lifecycle flow](https://developer.android.com/images/guide/fragments/fragment-view-lifecycle.png). When you navigating out of a fragment, it's switching to `CREATED` state (so `onPause` and `onStop` are called), but **view is destroyed**(and `onDestroyView` is called). Next time you navigating back to this fragment, the view hierarchy is recreated (your `onCreateView` is called). So you should set your image url to the image view again.